# how to change button in listView while download process

Tags: android, listview

i've got a listview which contain in each row one button and text. I create a adapter extended by BaseAdapter, and in getView() method , i've got a listener linked with my button to start my intentService for download. The problem is how can remplace my button with animate icon download (while download), and change (again) this button when intentService finish his job. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can create a download list in your adapter class like this:
`ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();`
and then if download button click , run your service and add that cell to your list, then notify list and if cell is in list show animation instead button.
when your download finished , delete that cell from list.something like this:

adapter.class
in getView method

```
 if(list.contain((Object)position)){
    //show animation
 }else{
    //show button

    button.setOnClickListener(...){
       ....
       list.add(position);
       //run Service here
    }
 }
```

in your service remove that cell when download finished;